# "libiomp5.so cannot open shared object file" how to slove in Windows 10?

Tags: bash

I run a code using my Windows 10, using Bash. Then I run the code, I get:

> error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The program was written in Fortran. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11):

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libomp-dev
```

And this problem was solved.